# How to force Y coordinate in graphviz

Tags: coordinates, graphviz, dot

Is there a way to force y position, in pixel or inche, in graphviz using dot.

The `rank=same` is not suitable for my case.

The `[pos="x,y!"]` with `-Kfdp` could be a way, but I want to **let GraphViz determines the X** position.

Thanks