# Force x-coordinate with graphviz

Tags: coordinates, graphviz, dot

I'm wondering if, using graphviz, there is a way to force the x-position of a node and only the x-position, the y-position should be figured out. I know the `pos` attribute can be used to force both x & y but I can't find if it can be used only on x.
I am aware a very similar (y instead of x) has already been posted ([How to force Y coordinate in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101802/how-to-force-y-coordinate-in-graphviz)) but with no answer.

Thanks in advance.